# How to assign each column of an array to a specific variable?

Tags: java

Is this the right way of assigning each column in my data file to a particular variable?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //specifying the path to file
    String datafile = " C:\\Users\\rez\\Desktop\\sol_2.mcmc";
    //reading the file
    double[][] mydata = FileReadingTools.getDoubleArray(datafile);

    double P_0; //days
    double M_0; // in days
    double e_0;
    double w_0 = Math.toRadians(0);

    double[][] list = new double[3000][50];
    for (int sol = 0; sol < 3000; sol++) {

        list[sol][0] = P_0;
        list[sol][2] = M_0;
        list[sol][3] = e_0;
        list[sol][4] = w_0;

        System.out.println(P_0 + " " + M_0);
    }
```

Comment: You should take a look into the idea of self documenting code.

Comment: Have you at least tried to compile this code? I doubt it. You don't seem to understand how assignments work. `a = b` means: *the variable a takes the value of the variable b*.

Comment: And it's not surprising, since you try to assign the unitialized variable P_0 (and M_0, etc.) to `list[sol][0]`.

Comment: @JBNizet elliot corrected the initialization error

Comment: @austinwernli good idea, i`ll try to edit it and make variables more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have swapped the left and right with your variable assignments. You want to assign the values *from* the array. Also, please use more descriptive variable names. I think you wanted something like,

```
for (int sol = 0; sol < mydata.length; sol++) {
    P_0 = mydata[sol][0]; // mydata v-- as noted in the comments. ---v
    M_0 = mydata[sol][2];
    e_0 = mydata[sol][3];
    w_0 = mydata[sol][4];
```

Alternatively, you could use `printf` and access the array directly with something like

```
System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f", mydata[sol][0], mydata[sol][2]);
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite right either. If you notice, he loads "mydata", and doesn't use it, but also creates "list", but doesn't put anything into it accept in the loop.

Comment: @Daniel correct. so how do I link mydata to my loop and print those variables from my datafile?

Comment: @Daniel Well spotted. Edited to demonstrate iterating over `mydata`.